# For-in с объектом window

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив объектов в глобальном пространстве имён. Требуется получить массив имён этих объектов, которые имеют определённое свойство. Делаю так:

```
var test = {
    pr: true
}

alert(getObjName('pr'))

function getObjName(key) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var obj in window) {
        if (window[obj][key]) arr.push(obj)
    }
    return arr
}
```

Пробовал вместо 
window[obj][key] 
window[obj].hasOwnProperty(key) 
результат тот же. Если вместо arr.push(obj) поставить alert(obj), то искомый объект отобразится. Если же убрать key из window[obj][key] , то мы получим массив свойств window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код рабочий, за исключением того, что нет проверки на существование самого `window[obj]`. Так как в `window` довольно много служебных свойств некоторые из них могут иметь значение `null` и при попытке взять у `null` свойство будет соответствующая ошибка.

Для решения достаточно исправить условие следующим образом:

```
window[obj] && window[obj][key]
```

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо!